# former php user trying to learn ruby...very tough

Tags: ruby

i write something in ruby thinking that it will work as it did in php but no!

i realized that you need to clone objects using .clone

merely associating to a variable doesn't work !

in php this worked fine!

it took 2 days until i discovered this error!

what tutorials can i read to get firm grasp on ruby ?!

Comment: cloning is something that you should rarely need to use - what are you trying to do? Can you post an example of some code that shows your difficulties?

Comment: a = myObj.new
b = a

in this case, b and a point to the same thing. Exactly.

a.hello = 2
puts b.hello
# output: 2

The same was true with PHP5, as pass by reference became the default for objects in PHP5, where as in previous versions of PHP it was pass by value.

Comment: As an aside, you'll probably find using .dup preferable to using .clone, particularly when you start dealing with objects that have been frozen.  The .clone method maintains the frozen status, where as .dup does not.

Answer (score 4):

[Why's poignant guide to ruby](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2236084/Whys-Poignant-Guide-to-Ruby)

Comment: While I find that Why's poignant guide is a nice piece of work in the artistic sense, somehow it just didn't click with me at all on a technical level. It's nice to know that I can write code with Ruby that reads like an English poem, but somehow, ironically, he never sufficiently explains **why**. Or is it just me?

Comment: i agree i couldnt stand this guide with all its comic distractions. i found it very annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look at the [Pickaxe](http://www.rubycentral.com/book/) online.

Answer (score 1):

[Beginning Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223634) by Peter Cooper is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new Ruby user as well. What I did was build a web app first with Rails and then move into the Ruby core. This is the book I started with.

[Foundation Rails 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210397)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this book: [Rails for PHP Developers](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/1934356042?ie=UTF8&ref_=sr%5F1%5F1&s=books-intl-de&qid=1258596277&sr=8-1&linkCode=shr&camp=3206&creative=21426&tag=preiswerteswe-21)